# What is the incident Black Widow and Hawkeye are talking about?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, dialogue, the-avengers

In [*The Avengers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Avengers_(2012_film)), during the fight with the aliens from Chitauri before Bruce Banner shows up at the fighting spot, there is a dialogue between Black Widow (Natasha Ramanova) and Hawkeye (Clint Barton).

From [Springfields](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=avengers-the-2012):

> Captain America: You think you can hold them off?
>
> Hawkeye: Captain, it would be my genuine pleasure.
>
> Black Widow: **Just like Budapest all over again!**
>
> Hawkeye:  You and I remember Budapest very differently.

Is this from Black Widow and Clint Barton's back stories and operations? Do we know what happened at the Budapest operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is a case of what is known on as ["The Noodle Incident"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoodleIncident), or one of the similar tropes linked to from that TVTropes page. Essentially, it doesn't matter what happened in Budapest. It's mentioned just to establish a history between Black Widow and Hawkeye, letting the viewers know that they've fought together before, but have different views on how things work. It's a strategy for establishing characterization and background with a handful of words, and I think it works great here.

Comment: We already know that there is some background between them when Black Widow talks to Loki. Hawkeye was sent to assassinate her but didn't. It ended in a good way. I am interested to know what is Budapest incident specifically. Any info about it in detail is enough.

Comment: Just spent the last half hour scrounging through the internet, wasn't able to find a single thread of anything that gives any kind of detail regarding Budapest experience (aside from a slew of horrible fan-made trailers). Given this, @AvnerShahar-Kashtan 's response is most appropriate. +1.